Google OAuth2.0 using the authorization code received on the client-side for token exchange results in a 400 Bad Request error
I'm implementing Google OAuth2.0 authorization using Next.js on the client-side and Node.js with Express on the server-side. Here's my problem:

I successfully open a popup for Google authorization from the client.
The user authorizes in the popup, and I'm redirected to my client redirect URI where I execute the following code:

function OAuthCallback() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.name = "OAuthPopup";
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (window.opener) {
      window.opener.postMessage({
        search: window.location.search,
        code: params.get("code"),
        error: params.get("error")
      });
      window.close();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={st.container}>
      <Text<"h1"> as='h1'>
        Redirect to <span className={st.flippo}>Flippo</span>!
      </Text>
    </div>
  );
}


After the user is redirected to my client-side app, this script sends the authorization code back to the parent window using window.opener.postMessage. The popup then closes, and the parent window intercepts the event.
In the parent window, I send the authorization code to my server using axios. Here, I initiate a request to Google's token endpoint to exchange the code for tokens.
Despite the fact that the code and all the parameters seem correct, I receive a 400 Bad Request error from Google

I checked and verified the correctness of the authorization code by logging it and comparing it with the one passed to the server. Everything matches.
Server-side Code:
Here is how I'm making the request to Google on the server side:
const url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
const options = {
  client_id: GoogleEnv.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: GoogleEnv.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  code, // the authorization code from the client
  redirect_uri: GoogleEnv.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL,
};

const response = await axios.post(url, options, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
});


When I directly redirect the popup window to the server for code handling (without passing it through the client), everything works correctly, and Google returns the tokens.
When using response_type=token instead of response_type=code in the initial authorization request, I can get the token directly on the client, and everything works as expected when sending it to the server.
I double-checked all the parameters (client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, code) — they all match and are correct.

My Questions:

Why does Google return a 400 Bad Request when I pass the authorization code from the client to the server for the token exchange?
Could Google be binding the authorization code to a specific redirect host or mechanism?
Is there any difference in how Google processes requests when the code is sent from the client compared to when it is handled directly by the server?


Dont mix them just use server sided

@LindaLawton-DaImTo, is what I’m trying to do considered bad practice?
My goal is to display a loading screen on the client side while the server processes the data, so that the user is informed that the request is being handled, and also to display an error message in case something goes wrong.
If I redirect the user from Google directly to my server to handle the authorization code, I’m not sure how I can achieve this type of behavior. Is there a better approach to achieve this flow?

you may want to consider the fact that generally, server-side code runs first.    How will it  process your client side code?

I was simply trying to achieve the same effect as with a normal request. For example, when entering a search query, a loader is displayed while data is being fetched from the server. I wanted to implement the same behavior during registration and authentication. Maybe all of this is unnecessary and I shouldn’t worry about it too much.
